# How to match with both substring and string itself?

Tags: regex, token, lex

I m trying to tokenize bunch of code with lex and match different types of keywords with different regexes. When following regex matches, it tokenizes whatever it matched with "VARIABLE";

```
[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

And following matches with the print statement;

```
\s*print\((.*?)\)\s*
```

What I need is when following statement go through lexical analysis;

```
myVar_12
print(myVar_12)
```

Tokens should be like;

```
VARIABLE
PRINT VARIABLE
```

But what I get is;

```
VARIABLE
PRINT
```

I started to learn about regex like yesterday and could not figure out what should I do. So please pardon my meaningless regexes.

Comment: Is your goal to be able to use `print` both as a variable name and as a keyword, depending on whether it's followed by a parameter list?

Comment: No, print must be only keyword. What I need is when I type inside parentheses followed by print, it should matched some. For example when I typed print(someVar) it should match both print and someVar because print() is PRINT and someVar is VARIABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've clarified in a comment that you want `print` to be a keyword regardless of whether it's followed by a parameter list or not. Therefore the parameter list should not be part of `print`'s regex¹. The regex to match `print` should simply be `print`.

```
print                   return PRINT;
[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*  return VARIABLE;
```

Note that the order matters because the input "print" could be matched by both regular expressions and if multiple regular expressions produce a match of the same length, `lex` uses the one that comes first in the file. So keywords should always be defined before the rule for identifiers.

You'll also want to recognize parentheses as their own tokens and to ignore white space (presumably).

---

¹ In fact it should be part of the regex either way. But if you wanted `print` to be a contextual keyword, you'd need a different solution.

Comment: So, should I tokenize parenthesis as well? I mean when I used your regex with the following it will work fine: print myVar. However if I use it with print(myVar) it would say PRINT unknownchar VARIABLE unknownchar. (I return unknownchar for anything else that is not tokenized). Is there any way to do it without tokenizing parentheses but return PRINT VARIBLE with print(myVar)?

Comment: @zodiac645 "So, should I tokenize parenthesis as well?" Yes. "Is there any way to do it without tokenizing parentheses" You could ignore parentheses (by not returning anything in the action associated with them), but then your parser would have no way to distinguish between `print(var)` and `print var` (assuming spaces are ignored as well, but if they're not that'd still leave you unable to distinguish `print var` from `print (var)`). In most scenarios you'll want parentheses to be tokens.